# Replacement for antique fan capacitor

Tags: capacitor, fan, replacement

Could anyone recommend a replacement capacitor for an sk, mp capacitor 2uf 350v?. This one was used as a starter for an old fan.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You want a **film capacitor** rated for 350VAC or higher. I see 12 different types in stock at Digikey at prices from a few dollars USD up. For example, Kemet C274ACF4200LF0J, not the cheapest but a convenient package perhaps.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Search for motor-start capacitors. They are non-polarized electrolytic capacitors that are specifically designed for that duty. However 2uf seems small for a start capacitor. It also seems unlikely that a fan would have a start capacitor. Start capacitors are usually used for motors that require a high starting torque. Fans have a very low starting torque requirement.

The motor more likely has a permanently connected capacitor, a motor-run capacitor. If that is the case you need to search "motor run" rather than "motor start" that type of capacitor will not be electrolytic.

In either case, the value does not need to be exact.